# UIPIckerView in UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, uipopovercontroller

I'm not trying to resize the PickerView's height.  I'm fine with having the default size, which I believe is 320 x 216.  I created this code to present a pickerView in my popovercontroller, however, I get these messages on the console:

2

```
011-06-30 13:18:28.125 MiGenome[64357:207] -[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 1024.0 pinned to 216.0 
2011-06-30 13:18:28.126 MiGenome[64357:207] -[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 448.0 pinned to 216.0 
2011-06-30 13:18:28.127 MiGenome[64357:207] -[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value -16.0 pinned to 162.0
```

I don't know why I get this since I'm trying to use the picker default size in the popover.  Here's my code. Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)presentSortPopover {
    UIViewController *sortViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UIPickerView *sortPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sortViewController.view.bounds.size.width, sortViewController.view.bounds.size.height)];
    sortViewController.view = sortPickerView;
    sortViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
    sortPickerView.delegate = self;
    sortPickerView.dataSource = self;
    sortPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    self.SortPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:sortViewController];
    [self.SortPopover presentPopoverFromRect:_sortButtonPop.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    [sortPickerView release];
    [sortViewController release];
}
```

Comment: What are the bounds (size/width) of your sortViewController? You're setting the frame of the UIPickerView to that in your initWithFrame method; if it's not the size you want, you'll have to change the CGRectMake call to include the correct value.

Comment: Yeah I tried that originally also.  I tried creating the frame of my sortViewController to be 320,216 as well, but I still get those statements on the console.  Also, if I changed the height of the 216 to 500, I would NOT see any change.  I only saw change if I changed the contentSizeForViewInPopover property.

Comment: Any luck with this issue. I am having that exact same problem. I think the Popover is trying to resize the frame of the picker.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem until I embedded the `UIPickerView` in a generic `UIView` with the same dimensions `(0, 0, 320, 216)`, and set the view controller's view property to the `UIView`.

Also, I used the `setPopoverContentSize:animated:` method on the `UIPopoverViewController` to set the popover dimensions, rather than setting it on the `UIViewController`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was also getting the `-[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value`... error because I had set the autoresizingMask on the UIPickerView.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is the culprit.

```
UIPickerView *sortPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sortViewController.view.bounds.size.width, sortViewController.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

try

```
UIPickerView *sortPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I originally had.  I tried originally making the rect 320, 216, then I thought maybe that was giving me the problem.  So I tried not setting it to a number, and just fill out the frame.  Unfortunately, I get the error both ways.  :-\.  Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewController` has a method called `contentSizeForViewInPopover`.
If you set the expected size for your view controller using it (using a `CGSize`) you will be able to prevent the `UIPopoverController` from resizing itself wrong.